# Is it possible to solve this inequality?

Tags: inequality, mathematica

I need to solve this inequality for $j$ and I am having a hard time. I also tried to use Mathematica but it did not work.

[image: Mathematica image]

Do you have any idea of how to proceed? Any tips on the procedure is very appreciated.

$$
\underset{j}{\mathrm{max}} \hspace{0.1cm }(1-\beta) \frac{\beta j(\lambda -1)+z(\beta+\beta(-q)-1)-\beta\lambda w}{(\beta -1)(\beta q +1)} -j > 0
$$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What values can all the variables take?

Comment: The expression is linear in $j$, so it’s not hard to isolate $j$, assuming you know if things are positive or negative. Strategy: multiply with the denominator, then factor out the two $j$’s. Now you’re down to one $j$, and’s you should be able to finish.

Comment: Btw, I assume you’re looking for the maximum $j$ so that the inequality is satisfied? This would actually be $\max\{j: foo<bar\}$, or you can write it in words. What you’ve written is technically nonsensical.